# Hello guys how can i scrap cookies after login gmail using oauth gmail doc?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, oauth, gmail

i want to grab cookies after gmail oauth check login is true and i can login without password!
i use this script php to check (gmail) but now i want grab cookies after this
save cookie in file cookie.txt
`

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
  //google-api-php-client--PHP5.6/
// init configuration
$clientID = 'clientID';
$clientSecret = 'clientSecret ';
$redirectUri = 'redirectUri ';
   
// create Client Re quest to access Google API
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientID);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
  
// authenticate code from Google OAuth Flow
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
   
  // get profile info
  $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
  $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
  $email =  $google_account_info->email;
  $name =  $google_account_info->name;

  // now you can use this profile info to create account in your website and make user logged in.
} else {
  echo "<a href='".$client->createAuthUrl()."'>Google Login</a>";
}
?>
```

`
Any idea?

i want scrape the cookies after request checker

Comment: Cookies what cookies?  Could you clarify what you mean?  What part of your code would you expect to be setting a cookie?

Comment: yes i want grab the set-cookies after user  login

Comment: Where in your code are you setting a cookie exactly?  if you think the library is doing it you are mistaken

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.